# Access client certificates installed on a device from within an application

Tags: ios, certificate, private-key

I want to encrypt some data (NSData for instance)in my iOS application using the certificate installed on the my iOS device.I may only need the private key to encrypt the hash but is there a way to grab the private key from the global keychain.Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Best (in my opinion) you put the private key and certificate that you want to use on the keychain (or keychains of other 3rd party apps that share the same provisioning certificate).

As for the actual loading of the p12 we do use openssl (we did write a obj-c wrapper around it) to decode the .p12 that we send to the app.